# Count permutations with given longest increasing subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, algorithms

**Problem:** Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and a set $A \subset \{ 1,\ldots,n \}$ sorted in ascending order, find the number of permutations $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $A$ is a longest increasing subsequence of $\sigma$.

($A$ need not be the only longest increasing subsequence of $\sigma$.)

A solution might be expressed as a formula or an algorithm.

This question is inspired by [this puzzle on Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122422/permutations-with-given-longest-increasing-subsequence). Can you get a solution efficient enough to answer that question? Clearly, checking all $n!$ permutations is out of the question, as each one requires $O(n\log n)$ time by a clever Patience Sort algorithm (or $O(n^2)$ by dynamic programming).

Comment: The RSK algorithm gives a bijection between permutations and ordered pairs of Young Tableaux. This bijection plays nicely with longest increasing subsequences. This might lead to an answer. Read _The surprising mathematics of longest increasing subsequences_ for more info.

Comment: Page 82 of the book Mike Earnest cites provides a nice asymptotic result.  For sufficiently large $n$, the length of the longest increasing subsequence of a random permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ may be expressed (loosely) as $2 \sqrt{n} + \xi \, n^{1/6}$, where the random variable $\xi$ is very likely to be between $-6$ and $3$, with a mode of around $-2$.